# verbose stack Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to run the local server using `npm start` for my React app that I am working on. Which worked fine yesterday. But when I try to run it today I get the following error message see below. I tried some solution son internet, like reinstalling `npm install`, deleting `package-lock.json` file and `package.json`, recreating those files, installing missing modules `npm-install-missing` but no luck. Please help :)

```js
 0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/Applications/anaconda3/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/Applications/anaconda3/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'start' ]
2 info using npm@6.14.8
3 info using node@v11.14.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle amazon-clone@0.1.0~prestart: amazon-clone@0.1.0
6 info lifecycle amazon-clone@0.1.0~start: amazon-clone@0.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle amazon-clone@0.1.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle amazon-clone@0.1.0~start: PATH: /Applications/anaconda3/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/Users/joseftichanek/Desktop/React_Amazon/node_modules/.bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Applications/anaconda3/bin:/Applications/anaconda3/condabin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin
9 verbose lifecycle amazon-clone@0.1.0~start: CWD: /Users/josef/Desktop/React_Amazon
10 silly lifecycle amazon-clone@0.1.0~start: Args: [ '-c', 'react-scripts start' ]
11 silly lifecycle amazon-clone@0.1.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle amazon-clone@0.1.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: amazon-clone@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/Applications/anaconda3/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:193:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Applications/anaconda3/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:193:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:999:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:266:5)
14 verbose pkgid amazon-clone@0.1.0
15 verbose cwd /Users/josef/Desktop/React_Amazon
16 verbose Darwin 19.6.0
17 verbose argv "/Applications/anaconda3/bin/node" "/Applications/anaconda3/bin/npm" "start"
18 verbose node v11.14.0
19 verbose npm  v6.14.8
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error amazon-clone@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the amazon-clone@0.1.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: Are you sure you have the package.json file in the work project ?

Comment: Yes, I have a package in that folder `/Users/josef/Desktop/React_Amazon/package.json` plus it worked fine yesterday. I don't know why does it have a problem with the path now.

Comment: After reinstalling npm I am getting a different error message, see edited version

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `package.json` file at the expected location:

```
'/Users/josef/Desktop/React_Amazon/package.json'
```

Comment: Yes I have a `package.json` in my `React_Amazon` folder.

Comment: After reinstalling npm I am getting a different error message, see edited version